# Sort by value in ng-repeat (key, value) pair from object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting

I'm new to AngularJS. Using API I am getting key - value pair with sports

```
$scope.sports = { 1: "Soccer", 2: "Tennis", 3: "Basketball" ... };
```

Is this possible to sort items by sport name:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="(id, value) in sports | orderBy:'value'">
      <a ng-href='/page/{{id}}'>{{value}}</a>
  </li>
 </ul>
```

this doesn't work at all

https://jsfiddle.net/ak657soa/1/

```
 now is
--------------------
    Soccer // id: 1
    Tennis // id: 2
    Basketball // id: 3
    MMA // id: 4
    Street dance // id: 5
    Aerobics // id: 6
    Aerial hoop // id: 7

should be
    --------------------
    Aerial hoop // id: 7
    Aerobics // id: 6
    Basketball // id: 3
    MMA // id: 4
    Soccer // id: 1
    Street dance // id: 5
    Tennis // id: 2
```

I tried to sort them inside controller with underscore.js (I used it in different view) but then I lose information about ids. Like here: https://jsfiddle.net/vmbme3yw/1/

How can I deal with orderBy value in AngularJs where are (key, value) pairs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy) says, *orderBy* expects an `array` as input, not an object.

Thus the solution is turning your object into an array. You can do this using `reduce` method by passing a *callback* function as `argument`.

```
$scope.sports = Object.keys($scope.sports).reduce(function(arr,key){
    arr.push({id: key, value: $scope.sports[key]})
    return arr;
},[]);
```

Also, you can use `map` method.

```
$scope.sports = Object.keys($scope.sports).map((key) => ({id: key, value: $scope.sports[key]}));
```

Now you can display your items ordered by `value` field.

```
<li ng-repeat="elem in sports | orderBy:'value'">
     <a ng-href='/page/{{elem.id }}'>{{elem.value}}</a> // id: {{id}}
</li>
```

Working solution:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.sports = { 1: "Soccer", 2: "Tennis", 3: "Basketball", 4: "MMA", 5: "Street dance", 6: "Aerobics", 7: "Aerial hoop" };
    $scope.sports = Object.keys($scope.sports).map((key) => ({id: key, value: $scope.sports[key]}));
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-app="myApp">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="elem in sports | orderBy:'value'">
       <a ng-href='/page/{{elem.id }}'>{{elem.value}}</a> // id: {{elem.id}}
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: The code would be more readable if it used `map` instead of `reduce`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer is not only a solution, but very understandably written :D